# Setting user-rights of application/directory after build

Tags: linux, permissions, labview

I have a question about the directories and files, which are generated, after building in LabVIEW on Linux.

When I choose a not existing path for the destination directory for my application, LabVIEW generates it automatically, as far as I got it, and then puts all the files generated in that directory.

My problem here is that it does this with the wrong permission for the GROUP (e.g. drwxr-xr-x) for both the automatically generated directory and the application itself (plus .alias file and Support Directory).

I would like to know if there is a way to configure LabVIEW so it creates these files with the permissions I want.

Thanks for any tips and tricks in advance.

I tried to find some information about that topic in Google and the NI-Forum but could not find any help.